# I do not understand the code, specially why the output?

Tags: java

Well the input I add is 1 2 3.0 4 5.0 6 -7.0 8 9.0
the outcome is x = 1.0, y=-7.0, z= 8.0 
I was working on this problem for over an hour, and I don't understand. Using shell script..(I made a stdin file, which has the input numbers and I made a code to create a stdout file. I have dyslexia, so I am having trouble following the logic here. So is a the user input, (1...9.0)? so testing ( a <30 ) = (1 < 30) ; since 1 = is the first user input?

input file (problem-in)

> 1 2 3.0 4 5.0 6 -7.0 8 9.0

shell script:

```
  javac Problem7.java
  java Problem7 > problem-in > problem-out
```

output file from (problem-out)

> x = 1.0, y=-7.0, z= 8.0

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
   class Problem7{

    public static void main( String[] args ){

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a = 0;
      double x=0, y=0,z=0;

       while( a<30 ){

          while(true){

             while( !sc.hasNextDouble() ){
                sc.next();
              }

             if( a<10 ){
                 x = sc.nextDouble();
                 if( x>0 ) break; 
             }else if( a<20 ){
                 y = sc.nextDouble();
                 if( y<0 ) break;
             }else{
                 z = sc.nextDouble();
                 if( z>0 ) break;
             }
            }
          a += 10;
         }
          System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z);
         }
     }
```

for "a" is that the user input? assuming a+=10 -> which makes a=11? is that correct? If so, then where do the 11 go?

Comment: what do you wanna do by the way?

Comment: What do u want and where are you facing the problem?

Comment: I want to understand how the user input goes through the scenario of the while loop> I need a step by step process to fully understand why the outcome is that.

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode? reading codes like these are usually best debugged.

Comment: @intropella I would suggest you make your inputs readable

Comment: How do I run it in debug mode?

Comment: @Abdi , well this is the user input in one line, the "space" is the comma. Here's a readable version: ( 1, 2, 3.0, 4, 5.0, 6, -7.0, 8, 9.0 )

I add it in the stdin file as 1 2 3.0 4 5.0 6 -7.0 8 9.0
in the stdout file it's x = 1.0, y=-7.0, z= 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your code given you will loop trough the code in the following order.. first x -> y -> z

take note of the values here

first run a = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0
sc = user input so = 1 2 3.0 4 5.0 6 -7.0 8 9.0

while(a < 30) #it since a=0 it enters the while loop

if(a<10) # since a=0 it enters the 1st if

sc = nextDouble() #gets the next number which is 1.0
it then checks if x>0 so 1.0 > 0 which means x is accepted and 'break' out of the while(true)
then a+10

so a = 10, x=1.0, y=0 , z=0

if(a<10) # since a=10 it goes to the second if which is if(a<20) and enters it since a=10

sc = nextDouble() loops until we arrive at the first negative number (many iterations where skipped because we cannot 'break' out of the while(true) until we find a negative number

sc = nextDouble() #gets the next negative number which is -7.0
it then checks if y<0 so -7.0 < 0 which means y is accepted and 'break' out of the while(true)
then a+10

so a = 20, x=1.0, y=-7.0 , z=0

since all if the ifs are false then it goes to else

sc = nextDouble() #gets the next number which is 8.0
it then checks if z>0 so 8.0 > 0 which means z is accepted and 'break' out of the while(true)
then a+10

it then breaks out of while(a<30) since a=30

which arrives at the answer of x=1.0, y=-7.0 , z=8.0

Comment: Ah, but how come my java gave me x=1.0? I didn't get the 3.0.
Thank you for explaining, I appreciate your time helping me out.

Comment: no problem! So just for my own clarification, once the it breaks out of the loop, it discard other numbers? Since it accepted 8, then it stops taking number such as 9 and discard it?

Comment: yes there is no need anymore to go to (or check) 9 because the condition that if 8>0 is already accepted.. same goes with 1>0 in the first one.. but we still needed to check the other numbers after 1 since y is looking for a negative number

Comment: Oh okay, that made more sense to me. I had difficult what numbers go what, and how I come about. I am very glad you helped me. Thank you for the help again!

Comment: you are very welcome.. since you have dyslexia try to write everything down.. and take it step by step.. so you will be able to understand it efficiently

Comment: yes, i printed out the code, and wrote notes on paper step by step.